# Problems calling sendTransaction from within an event handler

Tags: go-ethereum, solidity, contract-development, web3js, transactions

I'm having problems with `Error: Invalid number of arguments to Solidity function`. Basically, the problem comes when I call sendTransaction with an event handler. i.e. here's the code after hooking up a Solidity event:

`// premisObject was setup earlier to point at the Abi at the contract's deployed address
const premisObject = this.premisObject
// rightsSetRights has been hooked up to the required event
const rightsSetRights = this.rightsSetRights 
rightsSetRights.watch(function (error, result) {
  if (!error) {
    const index = result.args._index
    const hash = result.args._hash
    premisObject._setRights(hash,index, {gas: 200000}))
  } else {
    console.error(result)
  }
})`

That call to `premisObject._setRights(hash,index, {gas: 200000}))` fires the error. If I make the same call outside of the event handler:

`premisObject._setRights(this.state.hash, 0, {gas: 200000})`

....works just fine. I need to call `premisObject._setRights` inside that event handler, somehow, because that's when I know the value of the required index. Any ideas what's going on? Or perhaps you've got a cunning plan which means I can circumvent the issue?

Comment: Did you check your parameters index, hash and premisObject are correct?  Also I think some parameters my need a '0x' in front. Also if premisObject is a contract it doesn't seems like a good idea to have a public method name starting with `_`.

Comment: Yup, all checked, and all seem correct. I'm currently circumventing the problem by redesigning my dAapp by generating the required index, rather than getting it from the event handler.

Comment: ps. it isn't _setRights - it's setRights (that was a transcription error) ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never got to the bottom of this - I ended up redesigning my dApp so that I set, rather than get, the index.